# Setting other attributes in loop rivets js

Tags: javascript, html, rivets.js

I have a loop like this in revets.js:

```
<ul>
    <li rv-each-article="main_content.latest_articles">
        <p rv-on-click="controller.onArticleClick" rv-text="article.title" 
        data-url="article.url"></p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Unfortunately `article.url` is not being parsed by revets.js so the when logging the value to the console it just prints `article.url` while I expect it to get the actual value from the data object and print that out.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just prefix `data-url` with `rv-` like:

```
<ul>
  <li rv-each-article="main_content.latest_articles">
    <p rv-on-click="controller.onArticleClick" rv-text="article.title" 
    rv-data-url="article.url"></p>
  </li>
</ul>
```